# Is such writing okay in the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, comparative-constructions, comparative

> We don't have to worry much, for with as so small an amount as is in his possession he won't go far and we'll eventually catch him.

I've made up this sentence and I'd like to know if the "**for with as so**" and the "**as is in**" parts are okay? Didn't I break any English rules here?

Comment: How *absolutely* normal sentence can be made *complex* using superfluous words! Actually, I need to learn this - an *author style!* No offense, please! :)

Comment: Just asking: any specific reason to choose *'possession?'*

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, and it's not about money. It is about fuel.

Comment: I think it's better this way: "We don't have to worry for, with so small an amount as is in his possession, he won't go far and we'll eventually catch him." I would get rid of the "as" there. You could also turn the "for" into "because". The "for" there is a synonym for "because", but it's a little old-fashioned and not as common as "because" in that situation.

Comment: This sentence that you have created is a bit of a tongue-twister. I would even move phrases around and reword some of it: "We don't have to worry for he won't go far with  the small amount of money in his possession, so we'll eventually catch him."

Comment: Normally, in English, we use "as...as" in positive statements and "so...as" in negative statements. Your statement is negative, so it should be "so...as". You have a mixture above "as so...as". That is wrong; you have to pick one or the other. In some instances, they are interchangeable in Modern English, but there are some cases like the one above wherein the old rule of using "so...as" in the negative sounds better than using the positive "as...as".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sentence is a lot more complicated than it needs to be: that makes it hard for the writer to be sure that it is correct, and even harder for the reader to understand.

If you absolutely need to write something as complicated as this (and IMHO you don't need to here), it's generally a good idea to use the least ambiguous equivalant way of expressing each concept, for example **for** has two meanings (conjunction because and preposition intended for), so it is better to use **because** in a complex sentence like this.

> We don't have to worry much, **because** with as so small an amount as is in his possession he won't go far and we'll eventually catch him.

your original sentence is almost correct, but you can't use an adverb of degree after the first **as** in an **as..as** construct because **as..as** is a kind of comparative. For example

> as bald as a coot - *ok*
>   as **very** bald as a coot - *not ok*

Eliminating **so** and applying more conventional punctuation, we get:

> We don't have to worry much because, with as small an amount as is in his possession, he won't go far and we'll eventually catch him.

Alternatively, you can keep **so** and eliminate the **as.. as** construction:

> We don't have to worry much because, with so small an amount [of money] in his possession, he won't go far and we'll eventually catch him.

Better still, though, would be to cut out some of the entangled dead wood:

> We needn't worry: we will eventually catch him because he won't get far with the amount [of money] he has.

Comment: Isn't "**as that big a house as his**" a correct way of saying that a house is really big? I can't see a different way of saying it.

Comment: "I have just **as big a house as his**" is how I would say it. I don't think I would add a "that" between "as" and "big". My statement doesn't necessarily mean that he has a really big house; it means that the size of my house is comparable, if not equal, to the size of his house.

Comment: @SovereignSun: no, you can't say "as that big a house as his". **that** is an intensifier, which works like an adverb of degree. See the examples here for how you use **that** and **as... as** to express the same idea... https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/that

Answer (score 3):

> We don't have to worry much, for with as so small an amount as is in his possession he won't go far and we'll eventually catch him.

Grammar errors aside, I want to help you write in a way that is clear and easy to understand.

Use short sentences. Make them simple and to the point. Keep related topics together.

The very beginning and the very end of your sentence are one thought: "We don't have to worry much…we'll eventually catch him." The part in the middle is the reason behind that thought: "with as so small an amount as is in his possession he won't go far."

So let's take the beginning and end and make it one sentence. The reasoning in the middle will be a second sentence. (I assume the "amount" you're talking about is money.) And we'll correct the grammar and tighten up the wording:

> Don't worry, we'll catch him. He doesn't have much money and won't get far.